# UWP M3U stream Playlist

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

i have a M3U file with many live streams, how can access and open it?

```
myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("http://12345.net/09876.m3u");
```

This is working "fine", but only plays the first stream.
Any solution?
Thanks in advance.

M3U Example from wikipedia:

```
#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:123, Sample artist - Sample title
C:\Documents and Settings\I\My Music\Sample.mp3

#EXTINF:321,Example Artist - Example title
C:\Documents and Settings\I\My Music\Greatest Hits\Example.ogg
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please post a m3u file for example . 
I can remember m3u files were text files only . 
As far as I can remember you could open them using NotePad and look at their links . each link is in a line so you can easily separate them in your app too and play them one by one . 
Something like this can help you

```
var lines = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(App.ProgramsIndex, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) || line.StartsWith("#"))
            {
                //Skip This Line
            }
            else
            {
                //Do whatever you want .
                Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(line);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Ali. I put an example on the top. I can open it of course, but it's interesting what you said then. I'm going to try that approach.

Comment: So I thought true about these files . I added a code to my answer